# ¿Cómo determina el callback de el método Overlap en Phaser a que elementos se refiere cada argumento, si no permite pasarlos como parámetros?

Tags: javascript, callback, parámetros, phaser

Tengo dentro de mi función create() esta línea:

this.physics.add.overlap(person, coin, esconder, null, this);

... y fuera de create() esta la función esconder:

function esconder (personaje, moneda) {
moneda.disableBody(true, true); }

Pasa algo que no comprendo, si en el overlap invierto el orden ... overlap(coin, person, ... sigue desapareciendo la moneda(coin). ¿Cómo sabe mi función quién es quién, si no permite especificarlo como parametros en overlap?

Comment: Pues debe haber una implementación interna para determinar el tipo de elemento incluso cuando los envías invertidos. La mejor forma de averiguarlo es revisar el código fuente del repositorio. En todo caso, imagino que la firma de la función `esconder` debe ser fija, es decir que debes declararla siendo el primer argumento siempre `person` y el segundo `coin`. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Ya había revisado la API de Phaser y no encontré tal orden en la firma; de hecho ya intenté cambiando el orden de la declaración y carga de los elementos (pensando que tal vez eso originaba el orden del reconocimiento de los parámetros) y no cambió el comportamiento antes descrito. Saludos y gracias.